# Updating SQL Table Where Fields May be Null

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table that I want to update daily. The data about the records that need to be updated are pulled from the web, as a text file. I have a Python script that will read the data, and figure out which records need to be updated.

Given that the are potentially a large number of records that could be updated each day, I would like to do something like the following:

```
with get_connection_to('Database') as connection:
     cursor = connection.cursor()
     cursor.executemany(query, data)
```

The problem with that approach is that any of the fields may be potenitall be `NULL`\ `None`

So if I use a query like

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Active = 0
WHERE Field1 = ?
    AND Field2 = ?
    AND Field3 = ?
    AND Field4 = ?
    AND Field5 = ?
```

then any records that contain a `NULL` value won't get updated.

The best idea I've come up with so far is to loop over each row, inspect each element, construct the SQL query specifically for each update, and then perform each transaction separately. This feels like a very inelegant, and slow solution to the problem.

Has anyone got a better solution?

Comment: Did you ask your self why your table fields doesn't accept NULL values?

Comment: Could you just use COALESCE to replace your null values?

Comment: The fields accept `NULL`. The query doesn't work because `NULL` isn't equal to `NULL`

Comment: `COALESCE()` won't work (I don't think), because it still suffers from the same problem that the `UPDATE` statement won't find the records that already exist in the table with `NULL` values.

Comment: In that case you could add an **OR** Field is null to exclusively look for those null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Active = 0
WHERE NULLIF(?,Field1) IS NULL
  AND NULLIF(?,Field2) IS NULL
  AND NULLIF(?,Field3) IS NULL
  AND NULLIF(?,Field4) IS NULL
  AND NULLIF(?,Field5) IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. That's does exactly what I wanted.